# Accidentally deleted easybcd folder

Tags: ubuntu, grub, easybcd

I was trying to make a dualboot with ubuntu and windows 10. I didn't want the easybcd bootmenu but the grub so i deleted easybcd and other folder(I dont remember the name but it was in the C drive) from easybcd. Now when I boot i'm get this error: 0x0000098.
If I click on f12 on startup I can boot into ubuntu.
Does anyone know a easy way to fix this error? I realy need windows for school.

Comment: Did you **permanently delete** the options?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you deleted \boot folder on c: ?

You cannot boot Windows so you have to repair Windows boot.

1. If you don't have Windows 10 - [Download Windows 10 and create installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
2. Boot from installation media and run "Automatic Repair" from recovery option (eventually several times with rebooting after each run).

Later you can fix dual-boot using "Boot Repair" from Linux Live CD/USB.

I don't want to comment on EasyBCD functionality at all as it violates copyright from Microsoft and copyright from Free Software Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore grub bootloader from Ubuntu, **you need to install an application called 'Boot-Repair'**.

---

1. Open terminal and enter:

> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
>   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

2. When it installs open it up you should get something like this:
   [image: Repair Boot]
3. Click **recommended fix** (first option).
4. **Wait** till it is complete and restart

---

When it complete you should be able to *dual boot* Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: It doesn't works. I have still the same error.